# How to use ToolTip in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am creating my Portfolio and in the skills section I want to add a tooltip on the image for the name of the skill. following is my SkillCard.jsx and .css I am facing error as

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

SkillCard.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './SkillsInfoCard.css';

const SkillsInfoCard = ({ heading, skills }) => {
  const renderSkillInfo = (item) => (
    <div className='skill-item-container' key={item.skill} data-tip={item.skill}>
      <div className='tooltip' data-tip={item.skill}>
        <img src={item.slink} alt={item.skill} className='skill-item-img' />
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const renderRows = () => {
    const rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < skills.length; i += 4) {
      const row = skills.slice(i, i + 4);
      rows.push(
        <div className='skill-row' key={`row_${i / 4}`}>
          {row.map(renderSkillInfo)}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return rows;
  };

  return (
    <div className='skill-div'>{renderRows()}</div>
    )
  
};

export default SkillsInfoCard;
```

Comment: so, you only get that error when you *add a tooltip on the image*?

Comment: in the code wherever I add I am getting this error

Comment: wherever you add what?

Answer (score 0):

Not getting any error in code

```
import React from 'react';

const Abc = ({ heading, skills }) => {
 const renderSkillInfo = (item) => (
   <div className='skill-item-container' key={item.skill} data-tip={item.skill}>
     <div className='tooltip' data-tip={item.skill}>
       <img src={item.slink} alt={item.skill} className='skill-item-img' />
     </div>
   </div>
 );

 const renderRows = () => {
   const rows = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < skills?.length; i += 4) {
     const row = skills?.slice(i, i + 4);
     rows.push(
       <div className='skill-row' key={`row_${i / 4}`}>
         {row.map(renderSkillInfo)}
       </div>
     );
   }
   return rows;
 };

 return (
   <div className='skill-div'>{renderRows()}</div>
   )
 
};

export default Abc;
```